# How to hit third party API form node server.

Tags: node.js, api, express

IndiaSMS is a thirdparty providing sms service I want to hit this api form node server. Any way to request to third party api. Please help..

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
exports.sendOTP = function (userInfo, callback) {
console.log(userInfo);
    console.log('Inside SendOTP usin indaSMS');
    var indiasmsURL = 'https://app.indiasms.com/sendsms/sendsms.php?username=user&password=pass&type=TEXT&sender=Alerts&mobile=' + userInfo.mobilenumber + '&message=Your%20OTP%20for%203DClubHouse%20is%20' + userInfo.otp + '';
    console.log(indiasmsURL);
    router.get(indiasmsURL,
    function(req, res, next) {
        console.log('--------------------------');
        console.log(res);
        console.log('--------------------------');
    })
    callback('hello');
};
```

Thnaks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is Mikeal's request library see link [here](https://github.com/request/request) very useful

```html
var request = require('request');
request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body);
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios):

```
axios.get('https://app.indiasms.com/sendsms/sendsms.php', {
    params: {
      username: user,
      password: pass,
      type: 'TEXT',
      //...
    }
})
.then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Or using async/await, you can simply:

```
let response = await axios.get(indiasmsURL);
if (response.status == 200) {
    //console.log(`CC status ${response.status}: `, response.data)
}
```

You can build your URI like above (stored in `indiasmsURL`) or specify them in the `params` of the request if you would prefer.

Comment: Thanks..  The blue 

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest [snekfetch](https://snekfetch.js.org/) or [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request).